# Avoid "Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)" when dealing with LaTeX lengths

Tags: width, calculations, dimensions

My goal is to link to external video files in beamer presentations rather then embedding them directly into the PDF (e.g., with [media9](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/media9) package) to keep the size as small as possible.

I use the [hyperref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package to create a clickable area (a link) which contains a preview image of the video and [TikZ](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) to create a small play button as overlay to attract presenter's attention. The final result looks like this:

[image: vlink command preview]

I wrapped the hyperref and TikZ commands in an own command `\vlink[options]{name_of_video_file}` and I use the [pgfkeys](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfkeys) package so that my command can accept key-value pairs as options.

The `vlink` command runs fine when using `\textwidth` or integer dimensions like `2cm` (e.g., `\vlink[width=\textwidth]{my_video_file.mp4}`). **But, when invoking with `width=0.5\textwidth` or `width=2.5cm`, I get an `Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)` error** because my TikZ command uses `\fontsize{0.40\vlinkWidth}...` to set the overlay dimensions. Obviously, LaTeX expands `0.5\texwidth` to something strange which I don't understand (the [LaTeX Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Lengths) states it should be a length).

So, what is the correct way to handle the passed width here?

Any help is appreciated. :)

A minimal working example is attached below (please add a dummy picture named `BigBugBunny.mp4.preview.png` to avoid compilation errors):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{
    /vlink/.is family,
    /vlink,
    % Here are the options that a user can pass
    default/.style = 
    {width = \textwidth, color=black, opacity=0.25},
    width/.estore in = \vlinkWidth,
    color/.estore in = \vlinkColor,
    opacity/.estore in = \vlinkOpacity,
}
\newcommand\vlink[2][]{%
    \pgfkeys{/vlink, default, #1}%
    \tikz{
        \node (previewimage)
        {\href{run:#2}{\includegraphics[width=\vlinkWidth]{{{#2.preview}}}}};
        \node [align=center,color=\vlinkColor,opacity=\vlinkOpacity,text width=\vlinkWidth] at
        (previewimage.center){\fontsize{0.40\vlinkWidth}{\vlinkWidth}\selectfont\faPlayCircleO};
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Test `vlink' Command}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Use `vlink' to create a link to a video file.
        \item I.e., the video file is not embedded into the final PDF.
        \item Instead, the default video player is launched when clicking the link.
        \item The link area is a preview image of the embedded video.
    \end{itemize}

    \begin{center}
        \vlink[color=white,opacity=0.6,width=\textwidth]{BigBuckBunny.mp4}
    \end{center}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\fontsize{0.4\dimexpr\vlinkwidth}...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\vlinkWidth,` is a macro not a length register, you would see the same if you went `\def\zzz{100.5pt}` then used `0.4\zzz` as a length.

The macro would expand and give you `0.4100.5pt`  with two `.` and the error that you show.

As Ulrike commented you can use `\dimexpr` which is essentially an anonymous length register so  `0.4\dimexpr\zzz\relax` is again a valid length or in your case `0.4\dimexpr\vlinkwidth\relax`

Comment: Thank you very much @UlrikeFischer and @DavidCarlisle for providing a solution and also the background information to use an anonymous length register using `\dimexpr`.